# About uploading images to Firebase Storage (with image_picker 0.8.3+1)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, imagepicker

After the update in Image_Picker, "XFile" is used instead of "File" and "pickImage(...)" is used instead of "getImage(...)".

```
await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
```

this code now returns XFile.

**Related codes are below**

```
    XFile _image;
    final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

    Future getImageFromCamera() async {
      final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      setState(() {
        if (pickedFile != null) {
          _image = pickedFile;
        } else {
          print("No image selected");
        }
      });
    }

    Future<void> uploadImageToStorage(XFile imageFile) async {
      String imageName = "${AuthService().getCurrentUID()}";

      FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("photos")
          .child(imageName)
          .putFile(_image);
    }
```

**error**

```
The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.
```

I can't write "_image" in putFile(...). It asks me for "File" type. But _image is of type "XFile".
How can I upload an image into Firebase Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io' as i;

Future<void> uploadImageToStorage(XFile imageFile) async {
      String imageName = "${AuthService().getCurrentUID()}";

      FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("photos")
          .child(imageName)
          .putFile(i.File(_image.path));
    }
```

You need to convert it into a file object using `File` from the `XFile`'s path.